# How can I get Elasticsearch running on CoreOS?

Tags: elasticsearch, coreos

I've a CoreOS cluster with three servers (on Digital Ocean), at this moment running MongoDB. Now I want to start Elasticsearch on this cluster with 1 replica (not using the Mongo river).

I followed the description as outlined [here](http://mattupstate.com/coreos/devops/2014/06/26/running-an-elasticsearch-cluster-on-coreos.html).

Resulting in two services, `elasticsearch@.service` & `elasticsearch-discovery@.service`.

#### `elasticsearch@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch service
After=etcd.service
After=docker.service
Before=elasticsearch-discovery@%i.service

Requires=elasticsearch-discovery@%i.service

[Service]
KillMode=none
TimeoutStartSec=0
TimeoutStopSec=360
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill %p-%i
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm %p-%i
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/bash -c "echo PreKill and rm done;"
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /data/elasticsearch
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull dockerfile/elasticsearch
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo mkdir and docker pull done;"

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "\
    echo StartingUp; \
    curl -f ${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}:4001/v2/keys/services/elasticsearch; \
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then \
        UNICAST_HOSTS = $(etcdctl ls --recursive /services/elasticsearch | sed 's/\/services\/elasticsearch\///g' | sed 's/$/:9300/' | paste -s -d ','); \
        echo Key found; \
    else \
        UNICAST_HOSTS=''; \
        echo No Key found; \
    fi;"
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "\
    echo Starting Docker; \
    /usr/bin/docker run \
      --name %p-%i \
      --publish 9200:9200 \
      --publish 9300:9300 \
      --volume /data/elasticsearch:/data \
      dockerfile/elasticsearch \
      /elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch \
        --node.name=%p-%i \
        --cluster.name=nvssearch \
        --network.publish_host=${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4} \
        --discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled=false \
        --discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=$UNICAST_HOSTS;"

ExecStop=/bin/bash/ -c "/usr/bin/docker kill %p-%i"

Restart=on-failure

[X-Fleet]
X-Conflicts=%p@*.service
```

#### `elasticsearch-discovery@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch discovery service
BindsTo=elasticsearch@%i.service

After=elasticsearch@%i.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
    while true; do \
        curl -f ${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}:9200; \
        if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then \
            etcdctl set /services/elasticsearch/${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4} \ '{"http_port": 9200, "transport_port": 9300}\' --ttl 60; \
        else \
            etcdctl rm /services/elasticsearch/${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}; \
        fi; \
        sleep 45; \
    done'

ExecStop=/usr/bin.etcdctl rm /services/elasticsearch/${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}

[X-Fleet]
X-ConditionMachineOf=elasticsearch@%i.service
```

But if I try to run the service (`fleetctl submit / load / start elasticsearch@1.service`), it immediately dies:

```
elasticsearch@1.service     475f6273.../IP  inactive    dead
```

Running `fleetctl journal elasticsearch@1` results in the following message:

```
Mar 17 09:17:04 nvs-1 systemd[1]: Stopped ElasticSearch service.
```

That's all, no echoes I've added (to the service) are shown, or whatsoever. Anyone any ideas on how to get me further?

Comment: What does it say in the journal on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat simpler to get [Elasticsearch running with Weave](http://weaveblog.com/2015/01/20/elasticsearch-and-weave/). My blog post shows how to run it on Vagrant, however moving the same setup to cloud should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: _Disclaimer: I am part of Weave team._

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the same article you did and ran into the same issue. I tracked it down to the docker container not being available anymore, so I change the docker run command in the `elasticsearch@service` unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch service
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutSec=180
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /data/elasticsearch
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull elasticsearch

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
  curl -f ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:4001/v2/keys/services/elasticsearch; \
  if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then \
      UNICAST_HOSTS=$(etcdctl ls --recursive /services/elasticsearch \
                      | sed "s/\/services\/elasticsearch\///g" \
                      | sed "s/$/:9300/" \
                      | paste -s -d","); \
  else \
      UNICAST_HOSTS=""; \
  fi; \
  /usr/bin/docker run \
    --rm \
    --name %p-%i \
    --publish 9200:9200 \
    --publish 9300:9300 \
    --volume /data/elasticsearch:/data \
    elasticsearch \
    --node.name=%p-%i \
    --cluster.name=logstash \
    --network.publish_host=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} \
    --discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled=false \
    --discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=$UNICAST_HOSTS'

ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %p-%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm %p-%i

[X-Fleet]
X-Conflicts=%p@*.service
```

Apart from that I think, on your original post, you're missing some quotes, double quotes and have some wrong blank spaces.

This is my current elastic-discovery@service for reference:

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch discovery service
BindsTo=elasticsearch@%i.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
  while true; do \
    curl -f ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:9200; \
    if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then \
      etcdctl set /services/elasticsearch/${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} \'{"http_port": 9200, "transport_port": 9300}\' --ttl 60; \
    else \
      etcdctl rm /services/elasticsearch/${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}; \
    fi; \
    sleep 45; \
  done'

ExecStop=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm /services/elasticsearch/${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}

[X-Fleet]
X-ConditionMachineOf=elasticsearch@%i.service
```